# Another: NSString Compare Not Working in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to use the **IsEqualToString** method (which I have used succesfully before). But I get the following error:

**-[NSCFString IsEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa055e7b0**

Here is the code:

```
@interface EditHabitViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate> {

NSString *contactId;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *contactId;


-(void)updateContactInfo {
NSString *sSQL = @"";
NSString *sCheck= self.contactId;

// nothing to load? then leave: 
if ([sCheck IsEqualToString: @"0"]) {
    return;
} // end if
```

Notice that both sCheck and contactId are both declared as NSString. This is driving me crazy!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

You have some errant capitalization in `IsEqualToString:`-- try `isEqualToString:` instead.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that!! Thanks so much, my code works now!